# Is it possible to set a default zoom level that a website will be displayed in?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, css, heroku

When tested locally in chrome the page is displayed at 90% zoom, however on heroku it is displayed at 100%.

I have styled the page with the 90% in mind, is it possible to have the heroku page load in 90% as well?

Comment: Styling the page with a certain zoom level in mind is not a good UX design. Don't you simply mean a smaller font size and things?

Comment: Anyway, you can use `transform: scale` on the whole page if you want. Or `zoom` on browsers that support it. Still not a good idea though.

Comment: No i mean the zoom, my page is responsive and its switching "to early" on heroku.

Comment: You mean how to tell Heroku to display the content at 90% by default? In that case, sorry, not familiar enough with Heroku.

Comment: I think you should change your local Chrome back to the standard zoom level, and fix the page accordingly.